# Kali Linux keep asking username and password again and again! I Can't login!

Tags: kali-linux, login

> My problem is whenever I type user name and password; kali linux keep asking me again and again the username and password. I can’t get in to the system. However I can login in text mood in different tty by pressing ctrl+alt+f2.

I had Kali-Linux-2016.1-vm-amd64 installed in my VMware.

I wanted to upgrade Kali Linux to 2016.2 version.

So I opened the terminal and typed as below-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Everything went fine and upgraded then system asked a reboot. I rebooted the system then I faced a problem which denied me to login into kali linux and popped up with this message below-

```
"Oh no! Something has gone wrong." and "A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."
```

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Igc.jpg

I fixed this problem by using these commands

```
apt-get update
apt-get install x-window-system
apt-get install xorg
```

Then my Login GUI screen appeared but whenever I type user name and password kali linux keep asking me again and again the username and password. I can’t get in to the system. However I can login in text mood in different tty by pressing using ctrl+alt+f2.

> Watch the problem in video I’ve uploaded in YouTube
>
> YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg4sJ81AGa8

Please suggest me a solution!

Comment: Running out of disk space can cause this issue; in my case, I could log in as *root* but not as *kali*. So I logged as root to free storage from *kali* documents and downloads folders. Than rebooted.. and all sorted out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's happening because your display manager got corrupted somehow.

Try to reinstall lightdm and see if it works.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```